# GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm getting this error message repeated 3 times after implementing leaderboard/achievement coding:

07-18 10:27:02.351: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(14261): The Google Play services resources were    not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

this appears to be generated by the 'GameHelper.java' file in the imported 'BaseGameUtils' library project referenced as a library by my game app.

I have google-play-sevices_llb imported to my workspace, and its referenced as a library in the BaseGameUtils library itself. there is a google-play-services.jar in the Android Private Library of BaseGameUtils. there is a google-play-services_lib.jar in the Android Dependencies folder. there is a android-support-v13.jar in the base folder of BaseGameUtils (updated from v4). I believe everything is set up correctly on the developer and game.developer pages and I have the 2 required lines added in the manifest of my game app.

I see pages on this for google mapping and admob where the answers basically suggest ignoring it if everything appears to be working. however, I don't see pages on this error for leaderboards/achievement implementation and it does appear to be preventing the service connection here.

I'm unable to access services for leaderboards/achievements. I'm still getting abmod banners so my game app does appear to access services code, the services jar is also in my game app's private library.

Answer (score -1):

Please import google_play_services project in /sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject because you need resources -res's folder in this project.

You add google-play-services.jar in libs not enough.

Hope this help!!!!